# How to create list of txt folders with sql files from pandas dataframe

Tags: python, pandas

I would like to create list of txt folders with sql files based on dataframe columns.

Example:

[image]

I need to create list of txt folders named as my main_folder column which would have sql file named as my sql_file_x with sql query from column sql_query_x and sql file named as my column sql_file_y with query from column sql_query_y.

Answer (score 1):

You can use pandas apply to do the file operations.
Here is an example:

```
x='''main_folder,sql_file_x,sql_file_y,sql_query_x,sql_query_y
"a1111","a1111.sql","data111.sql","select 111","select 'dd',111"
"a2222","a2222.sql","data222.sql","select 222","select 'dd',222"
"a3333","a3333.sql","data333.sql","select 333","select 'dd',333"
'''
import pandas as pd, io, os
df=pd.read_csv(io.StringIO(x))

def createFilesFolders(row):
    os.makedirs(row.main_folder,exist_ok=True)
    with open(os.path.join(row.main_folder,row.sql_file_x),"w") as f1:
        f1.write(row.sql_query_x)
    with open(os.path.join(row.main_folder,row.sql_file_y),"w") as f2:
        f2.write(row.sql_query_y)

df.apply(createFilesFolders, axis=1)
```

Output:

```
.
├── a1111
│   ├── a1111.sql
│   └── data111.sql
├── a2222
│   ├── a2222.sql
│   └── data222.sql
├── a3333
│   ├── a3333.sql
│   └── data333.sql
└── solution.ipynb
```